# How and where do you encode the header and charset parameters for CSV files?

Tags: csv, validation, specifications, data-processing, rfc4180

The CSV spec ([RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180)) identifies `header` and `charset` parameters, but it strangely doesn't specify where they go, or how they're encoded. For `header` it says:

> The "header" parameter indicates the presence or absence of the header
> line. Valid values are "present" or "absent".

But *where* does this go in a CSV file or stream? And where does `charset` go?

See section 3 of the spec for the parameters bit. The whole doc is only a couple of pages of actual content, as we might expect for a CSV spec, but it leaves out critical details. Note that I'm not asking about a web server-to-browser scenario where there'd be HTTP header fields for MIME type or charset, but rather the general case of CSV files and streams.

Answer (score 0):

Confirming that there really is nowhere in a CSV data file to put those metadata fields, either as a file or as a stream.

Those two fields are - as you mentioned - only for cases where a CSV file is being exchanged via a MIME aware protocol, such as HTTP.

Other formats have found different ways around the problem. E.g. [JSON](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259) *must* be encoded using UTF-8. [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/) has an encoding in the prolog.